# Error - WebApp Implementation with Principal Component Analysis(PCA) - Azure ML Studio

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

After applying Principal Component Analysis PCA to my data set in order to achieve better model accuracy. The 13 features dimensions, I am reducing it to 10 features using PCA. Everything is fine till here.

After implementing the model in WebApp, it is building & seems fine in the studio.

In the testing phase of model prediction, Instead of displaying 10 features as an input, the UI system is showing the original features which is 13 & the output is showing 10 featu[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2jbw.jpg)res which does not have any feature names for the newly generated features which are 10. And also prediction is not working at all after executing it.\

Attached are the screenshots, Please refer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please also show your diagram of the experiment? This kind of issue happens when you are not setting the input of the model correctly according to your requirement. Please double check how you define your experiment.

One thing I want to highlight is, in the portal/ quick test page, all the input data will be the same as your original import data according to the document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/classic/tutorial-part3-credit-risk-deploy#deploy-as-a-new-web-service